# IMG tag does not display after INPUT tag

Tags: html, input, image

Given the html fragment

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
  <head>
    <title>Test JQuery AppendTo</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">      
    </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="Test1">
      <p>Just some text</p>
    </div>
    <form name="FORMPOST" method="post" action="showform.aspx" id="FORMPOST" >
      <label for="Test2">Test Label</label>
      <input id="Test2" type="checkbox" />
      <img src=\"add2.jpg\">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and given that the add2.jpg image is in the same directory as the html code, why does the image not display?  Note that if I move the image tag node to be inside the div node, it will display :(

Note the display does not appear regardless of whether I add the img tag at design time as above, or append it using the jQuery.appendTo function when the form loads.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the slashes :)

As a supplementary question, this problem arose when I was using jQuery to create the image tag at form load time.

So if you remove the image tag above and add the following script at the end of the html
<code>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var a = $("<img src=\"add2.jpg\">");
        a.appendTo($("#Test2"));
      });
    </script>
</code>

the image will not display.  FF shows the generated source with the img tag after the input tag - but will not render the image.

Comment: You should try appending to the form: `a.appendTo($("#FORMPOST"));`. `$("#Test2")` is an `input` element.

Comment: Thanks Daniel

How do I position it after the input element (there are many on the real live form - this is a stripped down test case) ?

Comment: OK, I'll encose the input in a another tag to control layout.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image tag doesn't look correctly formed to me

```
<img src="add2.jpg" />
```

Does this work for you like the above?

Comment: OP does need `/>` because this is XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you shouldn't have back slashes there for quotes. Can you give us a link to the page itself? Because that will work.

Comment: Thanks - Slashes were a typo :(
The page is in an internal app which is throwing an error in IE when loading the image dynamically with jQuery.  I'll post the jQuery fragment that is causing the problem.  FF does not throw an error - just fails to display the image.  IE 8 throws a script error.

Answer (score 1):

Were the backslashes in `<img src=\"add2.jpg\">` a typo? `<img src=\"add2.jpg\">` should be `<img src="add2.jpg" />`.

You need the forward slash to end the `img` tag because you are using XHTML.

Comment: Thanks - slashes were a typo.  Still have problems with fwd slash to close teh tag.